# Valores unicos de una columna ordenada

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un hoja con las columnas A(numérica) B(texto) C(numérico).
Quiero obtener las filas no repetidas para el texto de la columna B, pero que coja los valores de la fila ordenados primero por la columna A descendente y C descendente.

Ej:

> ```
> A       B        C
> 5       luis     80
> 9       luis     200
> 9       luis     250
> 3       juan     25
> ```

Busco:

> ```
> D       E        F
> 9       luis     250
> 3       juan     25
> ```

Lo he resuelto momentáneamente creando 3 columnas auxiliares ordenadas en las celdas E,F,G:

```
=query(A:C;"select B,A,C ORDER BY A DESC, C DESC")
```

y después en las 3 celdas que busco los resultados I,J,K:

```
=IFNA(BUSCARV(J1;E:F;2;FALSO);"")
=UNIQUE(E:E)
=IFNA(BUSCARV(J1;E:G;3;FALSO);"")
```

Soy nuevo en hojas de cálculo y lo que busco es si hay alguna forma de hacerlo directamente con un función solo en una celda

Answer (score 0):

Con una fórmula como ésta podrías obtener el resultado esperado. En la primera línea encuentra los nombres, en la segunda ordena el rango y en la tercera encuentra la primera aparición de ese nombre en ese rango ordenado. Considera cambiar los rangos si hay una fila inicial de encabezados:

```
=LET(nombres,TOCOL(UNIQUE(B:B),1),
rangoordenado,SORT(A:C,1,0,3,0),
BYROW(nombres,LAMBDA(cada,INDEX(rangoordenado,XMATCH(cada,INDEX(rangoordenado,2)))))
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. Estoy trabajando con Google Sheets y he modificado la función por lo siguiente: =LET(nombres;TOCOL(UNIQUE(B:B);1); rangoordenado;SORT(A:C;1;0;3;0); BYROW(nombres;LAMBDA(cada; INDICE(rangoordenado;XMATCH(cada;INDICE(rangoordenado;2))))))    Pero en el primer resultado me da: 9 luis 200, cuando tendría que ser 9 luis 250, y en la segunda fila da error, dice que no se ha encontrado el valor juan en xmatch